# How can audio files with different sampling rates be played at the correct pitch using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioengine

How should `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNodes` be configured to play audio files at the correct pitch when they have different sampling rates?

I read that the mixer can handle sampling rate conversion but I have not achieved this behaviour. I am using extensions to play looped audio segments and the players should function with compressed and PCM files; I don't know if that will dictate the solution.

I attempted to use AVAudioConverter inside an `installTap(onBus:bufferSize:format: block:)` block on the `AVAudioPlayerNode` but have been getting various crashes and was unsure if this was the right solution. Was I on the right track or is a simpler solution available?

```
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleRateMixerApp: App {

    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private let playerA = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    private let playerB = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("Play") { try? playFiles() }
            Button("Stop") { playerA.stop(); playerB.stop() }
        }
    }

    func playFiles() throws {
        _ = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
        try audioEngine.start()
        audioEngine.prepare()

        let pathA = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "32khz_sample_rate", ofType: "aif")!
        try setupPlayerNode(player: playerA, withAudioEngine: audioEngine, atPath: pathA)

        let pathB = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "48khz_sample_rate", ofType: "mp3")!
        try setupPlayerNode(player: playerB, withAudioEngine: audioEngine, atPath: pathB)
    }

    func setupPlayerNode(player: AVAudioPlayerNode, withAudioEngine engine: AVAudioEngine, atPath path: String) throws {
        engine.attach(player)
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

        let url = URL(string: path)!
        let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
        let frameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(file.length)
        let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: frameCount)!
        try file.read(into: buffer)

        player.scheduleBufferSegment(buffer, range: 0.25...0.75, looping: true)
        player.play()
    }
}

extension AVAudioPlayerNode {

    func scheduleBufferSegment(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, range: ClosedRange<Double>, looping: Bool) {
        let length = Double(buffer.frameLength)
        let startFrame = AVAudioFramePosition(range.lowerBound * length)
        let endFrame = AVAudioFramePosition(range.upperBound * length)

        guard let bufferSegment = buffer.segment(from: startFrame, to: endFrame) else { return }

        if looping {
            scheduleBuffer(bufferSegment, at: nil, options: [.loops, .interrupts])
        } else {
            scheduleBuffer(bufferSegment, at: nil, options: [.interrupts]) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension AVAudioPCMBuffer {

    func segment(from startFrame: AVAudioFramePosition, to endFrame: AVAudioFramePosition) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
        let framesToCopy = AVAudioFrameCount(endFrame - startFrame)
        guard let segment = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: framesToCopy) else { return nil }

        let sourcePointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(mutableAudioBufferList)
        let destinationPointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(segment.mutableAudioBufferList)
        let sampleSize = format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame

        for (source, destination) in zip(sourcePointer, destinationPointer) {
            memcpy(destination.mData,
                   source.mData?.advanced(by: Int(startFrame) * Int(sampleSize)),
                   Int(framesToCopy) * Int(sampleSize))
        }

        segment.frameLength = framesToCopy
        return segment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `AVAudioEngine`'s `connect(:to:format:)` passing in the `AVAudioFiles`'s `processingFormat` after loading each file. This ensures the `AVAudioPlayerNode`'s output is set to the same sampling rate as the file it will play.

The following code illustrates how this is done. The issue was not related to playing buffer segments so have not included that in the solution. Although audio plays correctly without disconnecting the player first, I was suspected it may leak memory so disconnected the node first to be safe.

```
import AVFoundation

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

func playFiles() throws {
    _ = audioEngine.mainMixerNode // Called to ensure mainMixerNode singleton is instantiated
    try audioEngine.start()
    audioEngine.prepare()
    
    audioEngine.attach(player)
    
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "32khz", ofType: "aif")!
    let url = URL(string: path)!
    let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    let frameCount = AVAudioFrameCount(file.length)
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity: frameCount)!
    try file.read(into: buffer)
    
    audioEngine.disconnectNodeOutput(player) // May be unnecessary 
    audioEngine.connect(player, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: file.processingFormat)
    player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
    player.play()
}
```